# sd-card in android virtual device

Tags: android-virtual-device, android-sdcard

I have created an Android virtual device with sd-card.

Now I want to create another Android virtual device with sd-card with same data.

**Where can I find the sd-card image file?**

By the way, I'm using Eclipse Juno on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are us Windows then go to this path

```
C:\Users\Dhaval\.android\avd
```

in avd folder found folder with your old emulator name. In that folder found sdcard(`Disc Image File (.img)`)